# Does IE10 support DOM4 Mutation Observers?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-10, mutation-observers

If not, then I can only hope for the same behavior as IE9 with Mutation Events?

I ask because I have no working IE10 platform currently, and Google search has yielded no results for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Only modern browsers do (Firefox, Chrome, Safari). Opera doesn't either.

Comment: @StevenLu - And there it will sit for at least a year on the list of many things IE10 can't do that any other browser can.

Comment: @StevenLu - Firefox and Chrome both support touch events so I assume they would but I haven't had a need to find out yet.

Comment: IE 10 is also modern browser and IE 11 supports mutation observer https://mobile.twitter.com/martinsuchan/status/305268817762861056

Comment: @OzhanDuz - IE10 is not in the same league as the others. I love how Microsoft likes to point to the next version of IE as an indication of how good today's version of IE is. Until IE can support as many properties as Opera/Firefox/Safari/Chrome, and it does not even come close, I would not call it a modern browser.

Comment: @OzhanDuz - And just to add on to my point. IE11 won't be out for at least another year. Then, according to your link, it will finally support what every other browser supports now and I don't know how long ago. This is typical of IE. Years late support, incomplete or incorrect, if it ever comes at all. Modern browsers don't do that.

Comment: IE10 is a "modern" browser. It supports different set of features (probably worth reminding that   Mutation Events is a proposal).  It implements some features which are not supported by browsers you described as modern (e.g. CSS Hyphenation).

Comment: @chodorowicz - IE10 is years behind any other browser in modern standards and practices. Inept at best, it's the worst browser on the planet. You can cherry pick and find a few properties IE10 supports but the mountain of properties it does not support is large and, while other browsers update every 6-8 weeks, IE won't update for at least another year. And there it will sit, years behind every single other browser. No web developer worth his salt uses IE10 or would state what you did. You, sir, are no web developer. Please quit embarrassing yourself.

Comment: @chodorowicz - To add, this topic is about mutation events, and you downvoted my answer even though 1) it was selected as the correct one and 2) it is correct. You seem to think it wise to down vote my answer just because Mutation Events is just a proposal but, since you aren't a web developer, you are oblivious to the fact that ALL standards are based on browser implementation and to excuse IE10 for not supporting something ALL other browsers support is something Microsoft might try to pull but no professional web developer would pull such a stunt but, as I said, you are no web developer.

Comment: @Rob This question wasn't about whether IE10 is modern and browser, but whether it supports specific feature, hence you comment was completely unnecessary. If you want to rant about IE I think personal blog would be a better place. We all know the history of IE, the problems it had and has. My only fault seems to be that I caught into this trolling comment. I'll leave your personal invectives.

Comment: @chodorowicz I responded to someone elses statement about IE10 and did not bring it up on my own. I notice the only time I read such responses are on weekends when the amateurs abound and it's one of the reasons I quit SO for over a year. You've reminded me of my reasoning.